# Wordpress - Adding default value to dropdown that links to no page

Tags: wordpress, html-select

I have the following piece of code which creates a drop down of a number of posts.

```
<?php
$mypostype = get_posts('post_type=rentals');
if($mypostype) : ?>
<form action="" id="myform">
<label for="myselect">Rentals</label>
<select id="myselect" name="select_post_type" onChange='document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;'>
<?php foreach ( $mypostype as $mypost  ) : ?>
<option value="?rentals=<?php echo $mypost->post_name; ?>"><?php echo $mypost->post_title; ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</select>
</form>
<?php endif ?>
```

This is working brilliantly apart from one thing and that is being able to add a default value to the drop down list that links to no page, some text like 'Select Rental'.

It would be great if someone could explain how to add this value in.

Thanks for your time and help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

By adding an `<option>` in the `<select>` and a slight change in the javascript `onChange` event by checking if the selected option value is not empty :

```
    <?php
    $mypostype = get_posts('post_type=rentals');
    if($mypostype) : ?>
    <form action="" id="myform">
    <label for="myselect">Rentals</label>
    <select id="myselect" name="select_post_type" onChange="((this.options[this.selectedIndex].value != '') ? document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value : false);">
    <option value="" selected="selected">Select Rentals</option>
    <?php foreach ( $mypostype as $mypost  ) : ?>
    <option value="?rentals=<?php echo $mypost->post_name; ?>"><?php echo $mypost->post_title; ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    </form>
    <?php endif ?>
```

This should satisfy your needs...

By the way you could do like this to echo the post links (absolute links):

```
<option value="<?php echo get_permalink( $mypost->ID ); ?>"><?php echo $mypost->post_title; ?></option>
```

Comment: This nearly does trick.  The default option is now populated however you are no longer automatically taken to a page when a post is selected.

Comment: I removed the `return` keyword in the javascript statement. I tested it and it's working fine.